# Datatable.merge like join

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two `DataTables` like this:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
```

`dt1`:

[image]

`dt2`:

[image]

I need to merge two `DataTables` and set to `GridView` like this:

```
dt1.Merge(dt2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But getting output like this:

[image]

How can I merge like this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add this lines:

```
dt1.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt1.Columns[0], dt1.Columns[1] };
dt2.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt2.Columns[0], dt2.Columns[1] };
```

Comment: Getting error like this: These columns don't currently have unique values."} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Comment: I don't have unique column. I need to join by 1. and 2. columns.

Comment: Then set col 0 and col 1 as primary key

Comment: Yes! It's work when I set col0 and col1 as primary key. Thank you.

Comment: @Ricardo I updated my answer, also if you had problem with showing data correctly try this `dt1.Merge(dt2, false);` instead of `dt1.Merge(dt2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with LINQ too:

```
var result = from a in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             join b in dt2.AsEnumerable() on new { C = a.Field<string>("CAR"),
             M = a.Field<string>("MODEL") } equals new { C = b.Field<string>("CAR"), 
             M = b.Field<string>("MODEL") } 
             select
             {
                CAR = a.Field<string>("CAR"),
                MODEL = a.Field<string>("MODEL"),
                DATE1 = a.Field<string>("DATE1") // You should write your type
                //...
             };
```